# Windows 10 Text is to big. How to make text smaller please

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

The icon pictures on the desktop are ok in size, but the text is big.  The word and outlook gui screens are very big and the text on google chrome bookmarks bar is big.  Scaling in windows 10 is set at 100% and cannot make it smaller. Everything on Google search is about making the text bigger, where this problem is to make it smaller

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
Window 10 has a bug that causes this problem.
The fix is to type a number in the scaling, eg 140%, apply and reboot.

On start up go to scaling and type 100%, apply and reboot.  Problem fixed.  It appears that the 100% displayed is corrupted, and by changing it upwards and then back to 100% overwrites the corrupted entry.

Answer (score 0):

Search up `text size` in the windows settings, what value is the slider at? You only mentioned about display scale, try lowering this value instead.